# How to check how long a video (mp4) is using the shell?

Tags: command-line, bash, video, scripts, mp4

I need to ftp upload all the mp4 files in a directory with length > 4 minutes using the shell. I can't find any script to check how long a video is. Does anybody have any idea how to do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844430/how-to-get-video-duration-in-python-or-django :-) hope this helps

Answer (score 36):

This will give you the length of a video.

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//
```

Comment: Also works for remote video urls e.g. ffmpeg -i "http://instagram.fewr1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/t50.2886-16/17014172_239108776550308_1175911794527436800_n.mp4" 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//

Comment: Is the FFmpeg log messages format guaranteed? If not, I don't like this much - it could stop working with any release.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i myvid` does output media info, but returns an error status (-1). The command `ffprobe` however does exactly the same but without the error (if worried about future behavior changing); e.g., `ffprobe -hide_banner myvideo 2>&1 | grep "Duration"` then `cut`, `sed`, etc; however there are options for customizing the output format as well (xml, json, txt, etc).

Answer (score 13):

[Mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/) is a fast tool for this purpose:

```
$ mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Duration%"  [inputfile]
```

You can find more options in [a more thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19091772/188159).

In my tests, `ffprobe` takes 0.3 seconds and `mediainfo` takes 0.09 seconds.

Comment: This gives weird results... like *2679600*... better to use `mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Duration/String%"  [inputfile]` ... which would get you something ike *43 min 50s*

Comment: This worked great for me on RPi in command-line-only mode

Answer (score 9):

[`exiftool`](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) (originally intended for reading camera metadata from image files, but later expanded to read and *write* metadata from almost *any* kind of media file) is very convenient to use for this. Run it with:

```
exiftool FILE.mp4 | grep Duration
```

You'll probably need to install `exiftool` first, but this is is easily done with the following command (on Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu etc.):

```
apt install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

Of course, this answer is just another alternative. Many of the other answers are good too. :)

Comment: I believe you can use `exiftool -Duration FILE.mp4` to just get the duration.  No grep needed ...

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use **avconv** command..

First you should to install:

[image: Install via the software center]

if you type the command with the flag -i, you will get information about the video:

`avconv -i test.mp4`

In the output there is a field called **Duration**

```
avconv version 0.8.4-4:0.8.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Nov  6 2012 16:51:33 with gcc 4.6.3
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':

  Duration: 00:58:28.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 888 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x404, 748 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 20k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 127 kb/s
```

Now you can use the command to only get the value of the field **Duration**

Type:

```
avconv -i file.mp4 2>&1 | grep 'Duration' | awk '{print $2}' | sed s/,//
```

In my case the result is:

```
00:58:28.05
```

58 Minutes and 28.05 seconds.

Hope this will helpful!

Comment: This can also be used with `avprobe` - no need for the `-i`, but it otherwise works exactly the same way. Or `ffprobe` for @per's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to [pers solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/224248/249367), this can be used on an entire directory:

```
for f in *; do ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d " " -f 4 | sed s/,//  | tr -d "\n" && echo " $f"; done
```

it can even be extended by `| sort` to have the files sorted by their length.

you can add this to `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` in order to be able to do  `lsvlength | sort` on a directory

```
alias lsvlength='for f in *; do ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d " " -f 4 | sed s/,//  | tr -d "\n" && echo " $f"; done'
```

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler:

```
avprobe file.mp4 -show_format_entry duration
```

Comment: I currently get the message "Option 'show_format_entry' is deprecated, use '-show_entries format=duration' instead"

Answer (score 2):

`ffprobe` is more elegant solution than `ffmpeg` which throws an error if not given the output path.

```
ffprobe video.mp4 2>&1 | grep -E '^ +Duration' | cut -d':' -f2- | cut -d, -f1
```

Answer (score 2):

Check all the videos in current folder with their names and lengths:

```
exiftool -T -Duration -FileName *
```

Prints:

```
0:01:38 vid1.mp4
0:09:54 vid2.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see there are numerous ways to accomplish this:
`ffprobe mediafile -show_entries format=format=duration 2>&1 | grep DURATION` where *mediafile* is the name of the file, will provide output similar to the below. The first being the duration of the first stream (typically video) and the second providing the duration of the second stream (typically audio)

```
  DURATION        : 00:21:40.132000000
  DURATION        : 00:21:40.062000000
```

A more succinct but slightly less accurate and resource intensive approach would be `exiftool -T -Duration mediafile` where *mediafile* is the name of the file, will provide output similar to the below.

```
00:21:40
```

Another good option is `mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Duration/String3%" mediafile` where *mediafile* is the name of the file, will provide output similar to the below.

```
00:21:40.132
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see duration of some videos in a directory , you can use following command

> exiftool * | grep ^Duration | cut -d' ' -f 26

Comment: No need to use `grep` and such. Simply `exiftool -T -Duration *.mkv` (or whatever file pattern)

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are all great as long as you combine it with:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181712/simple-way-to-convert-hhmmss-hoursminutesseconds-split-seconds-to-seconds
To get something like:

```
for movie in *                                         
  do
  duration=$(ffmpeg -i $movie 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed -e 's/,//' -e 's/\.[0-9]*$//')
  duration_seconds=$(echo "$duration" | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
  if [ $duration_seconds -gt 240 ]; then
    echo "the movie $movie is longer than 4 minutes: $duration"
  else
    echo "the movie $movie is shorter than 4 minutes: $duration" 
  fi  
done                                                       
the movie a_short.mpg is shorter than 4 minutes: 00:03:06
the movie mlong_147309001.mov is longer than 4 minutes: 00:10:44
```

I wanted to post this as I came across this question, but none of the above provided the link/answer to H:M:S->testable shell threshold. Hope you have a great day!